# No toilet shut off valve in my NYC apartment

Tags: toilet, valve

So I'm trying to find the toilet shut off valve so that I can install a bidet, and I'm stymied.

[image]

This is what is where the shut off should be, and I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

There are normal gate valves under my bathroom and kitchen sinks. I live in a large highrise completed after 2010 that is a mix of apartments and condos.

Is that just some kind of valve? I tried putting a precision screwdriver in the little hole and there wasn't a screw in there.

Is there an access panel somewhere? I looked under my bathroom sink and it's hard to access the back -- I have drawers I'd have to take out to get in there.

Is there just no toilet shut off valve, perhaps to prevent people like me from messing with their plumbing?

I'm going to ask my super as well, but I was curious if anyone on here had any ideas.

Comment: That is the shutoff valve, it's just missing the handle. You can buy a new handle at  a hardware store, or cautiously use vice-grips to turn it off, however, ideally, you'd want to get the main to the apartment shutoff and replace that valve. From the picture, it looks a bit chewed up.

Answer (score 3):

### That's a valve that's lost its handle

What you are looking at is the shutoff valve.  You simply aren't recognizing it as such because it has lost the handle/knob that you normally turn to actuate the valve.

I would try using a pair of pliers to turn the valve for now, and talk to the landlord about getting it replaced (probably with a quarter-turn valve).

Comment: The OP should also advise the super/landlord what they're about to do, in case he needs to shut off water from below. If that valve hasn't been opened for a long time, the seals may break, preventing you from shutting it back off. Also, the handles can be picked up for a dollar or two at any hardware stores (given the valve doesn't need to be replaced).